# CSS Float left question

Tags: css, css-float

The following code is injected into the page via jQuery.  I can't change that, but I can change the css:

```
<div id="slideshow-prevnext" class="slideshow-prevnext"> 
  <a id="prev" class="left"  href="#"><span class="invisible">Prev</span></a> 
  <a id="next" class="right" href="#"><span class="invisible">Next</span></a> 
  <a href="#" class="dot">&nbsp;</a>
  <a href="#" class="dot">&nbsp;</a>
  <a href="#" class="dot">&nbsp;</a>
</div>
```

I want the three

```
<a href="#" class="dot">&nbsp;</a>
```

appear on the left of and the two ("Prev" and "Next") on the right.

How can I do it? I tried `float:left` but does not work.

**Edit**: CSS is too long to post. Development site is here at : http://site2.ewart.library.ubc.ca/

Comment: Not my down vote, but you've asked a CSS question without providing the CSS you're currently using. Please make a demo on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net).

Comment: It is quite long. Code above is just a code snippet. Working page is here at: http://site2.ewart.library.ubc.ca. On the homepage, right below the carousel, the prev & next button should be on the right while the three dots should be on the left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not particularly happy with this way of doing things - ideally you should just change the Javascript.

- On `#slideshow-prevnext` add `position: relative`.
- On `#slideshow-prevnext .left` and `#slideshow-prevnext .right` remove `float: left` and add `position: absolute`.
- On `#slideshow-prevnext .left` add `right: 29px` and `top: 0`.
- On `#slideshow-prevnext .right` add `right: 0` and `top: 0`.
- On `#slideshow-prevnext a.dot` add `float: left`.

It looks like this when you're done:

[image: winner]

Comment: +1 - I had the same thing through the debugger but I thought it was a bit too hacky and not really xbrowser (IE)

Comment: I agree it seems hacky (*"I'm not particularly happy with this way of doing things"*). It should work in IE, as far as I can tell. My answer is somewhat useless now due to the fact that he can switch the order of the buttons (I wrongly assumed he couldn't or wouldn't, for whatever reason).

Answer (score 3):

The most basic answer:

```
  a.left, a.right { float: right;}
  a.dot { float: left;}
```

In addition, it looks like the stylesheet '/profiles/ubc_clf/themes/logie/style.css' line 37 is trumping your float:

```
  #slideshow-prevnext .left {
    background: url(http://site2.ewart.library.ubc.ca/profiles/ubc_clf/themes/logie/images/controller/controller_left_button_on.gif) no-repeat;
    **float: left;**
    height: 30px;
    margin-top: 8px;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 29px;
  }
```

If that is to be on the right, it will need to read:

```
 float: right;
```

In order to accomplish this, you'll need to provide a CSS style which is more specific than the #slideshow-next .left rule.  For example, place this in the page <head> tag:

```
<style type="text/css">
  #slideshow-prevnext .left, #slideshow-prevnext .right {
    float: right;
  }
</style>
```

Because the <style> tag on the page has a higher precedence than those loaded before it, the rule should override the float value.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please use the code button (curly braces) when posting code. Just highlight your code and click the button. You can also see a preview of your answer below the text input area. Give [this](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) a read. It's also accessible from the ? button in the edit/post answer page.

Comment: @drackir Mea culpa. Trying to do too many things at once = bad post. :)

Comment: Thanks Jeff. I changed it to float:right and then change the order of "Prev" and "Next" and now it works.

Comment: Oh, no. Works in FF but not in IE.

Comment: Floats have a history of inconsistent behavior between browsers of different vintages (WebKit, Mozilla, IE).  Which version of IE are you using?

Comment: This solution looks fine to me in IE7 and IE8. My answer seems somewhat pointless now - I thought the idea was you can't change your HTML markup "because jQuery makes it".

Comment: @thirtydot: this isn't actually changing the html, it's just changing the referenced style sheet.

Comment: @Chris Lively: The OP switched the order of the buttons in the HTML code from how it was since I wrote my answer. Promise. Edit: Now he appears to have changed them back :S

Comment: @thirtydot They have always been that way round? - Check the edit history... weird O_o

Comment: @Myles Gray: He was changing it on his live site.

Comment: @thirtydot - Apologies, I only looked at the site the once when I was going to post basically the same answer as you, I thought he couldn't change the JS as well...

Answer (score 1):

you can do it by this example.

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div style="float:left"><a href="">&nbsp</a></div>
<div style="float:right;"><a href="">Prev</a> | <a href="">Next</a></div>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
```

i have used Inline Css. You can do it by classes or external Css also.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your CSS it makes it hard to guess how you have this working.

Assuming `left` and `right` are css classes for floating left/right, just remove them and move the links down like so:

```
<div id="slideshow-prevnext" class="slideshow-prevnext"> 
  <a href="#" class="dot">&nbsp;</a>
  <a href="#" class="dot">&nbsp;</a>
  <a href="#" class="dot">&nbsp;</a>
  <a id="prev" href="#"><span class="invisible">Prev</span></a> 
  <a id="next" href="#"><span class="invisible">Next</span></a> 
</div>
```

You'll have to post your CSS if you want a better example.

Comment: Thanks. But I cannot change the codes. I have not figured out how to change/move codes generated by jquery and its plugins.